# How to compare df1 and df2 of unequal length and assign values in R

Tags: r

These are the definitions of df1 and df2:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y=letters[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame(x= rep(c(1,2,3),each=3))
```

I want to assign the value of column y in df1 to column y in df2, where the value in column x of df1 is equal to the value in column x of df2. As shown above df1 and df2 are of unequal length.

```
for(i in 1:length(df2$x)){
        df2$y[i]<- df1$y[which(df1$x == df2$x[i])]
}
```

I am not looking for short cuts to do this (no builtin functions please). I want to learn it the right way.

Is my logic correct?
If it is why is this not working?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Surely the "right way" is to simply call `merge(df1,df2)` and not re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @aix I agree with the above comment, but I don't think he's trying to re-invent the wheel. I think He's trying to understand how the wheel works, or at least how he thinks the wheel works. And that's a respectable endeavor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking what you call "shortcuts" is actually the right way to do things in R. But I do think that looping through manually is sometimes a good exercise. But in your "production code", ie code that you want to count on, use the built-in functions when they are applicable.

You're just missing one option for your `data.frame`. Everything else is fine. The problem is that by default, character vectors are input as `factors` in a `data.frame` and when you try to replace a value with a value from a `factor` vector it is replacing it with the underlying numeric index of that level. Here is the complete code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y=letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(x= rep(c(1,2,3),each=3))

for(i in 1:length(df2$x)){

    df2$y[i]<- df1$y[which(df1$x == df2$x[i])]
}
df2
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 a
3 1 a
4 2 b
5 2 b
6 2 b
7 3 c
8 3 c
9 3 c
```

See `?data.frame` for more info on the `stringsAsFactors` option

Since you seem interested in learning, here's a way you might have gone about debugging. Suppose your original commands are in a file called `temp.R`. Then

```
> source('temp.R')
> ls()
[1] "df1" "df2" "i"
```

`i` is left over after the for loop. Let's use it so that your following commands with `i` in them will work. You can reassign a value to `i` to see what your command would give for other values. Now lets start breaking your code down to see where the problem is.

```
> i
[1] 9
> which(df1$x == df2$x[i])
[1] 3
```

Looks good so far. 3 is what we expect it to be, right?

```
> df1$y[which(df1$x == df2$x[i])]
[1] c
Levels: a b c
```

Here is where you need to recognize "oh, this is a factor!". Whenever you see "Levels" the "factor" lightbulb should be lighting up in your head.

Let's see the value before we try the replacement just to be sure the rest of your code didn't accidentally modify it:

```
> df2$y[9]
[1] 3
```

Looks good. We know what happens after the replacement, so clearly something goes wrong with the assignment. Let's try this just to see what happens:

```
> df2$y[9] <- as.factor("c")
> df2$y[9]
[1] 1
```

Clearly something is wrong. Thus we've narrowed the problem down to here. Now we need to go back up to find out why we're replacing with a factor. Hopefully that will lead you to the `data.frame` help.

Things like this are annoying in `R` but you just have to have faith that there are reasons for behavior like this, and once you learn more coding in `R` and more of `R`'s philosophy, you won't have as many surprises such as this. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Xu, I cannot thank you enough. I spent the whole weekend working on this and became very frustrated

Comment: Hi Xu, I cannot thank you enough. I spent the whole weekend working on this and became very frustrated. I felt like giving up on R...just kidding.

Comment: @user1079898 Yeah, I know what you mean, but don't despair! The relationship that most people have with R is a love-hate relationship. But the longer the relationship lasts, the more love wins out :)

Comment: I hear ya friend....I think its going to last..and if I get stuck I have experts like you to help....thanks